# Uploading a SQLite database file to an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-s3, android-sqlite, android-device-monitor

I'm currently working on a project in Android Studio that implements AWS S3. The use of S3 is to upload/store my local SQLite database file on it so that I can download and use it on command. I realize that this is by no means the most optimal way to be using databases with S3.

I'm able to upload and download files to and from my S3 bucket. But for some reason, the database file is corrupted according to logcat. The SQLite database file is stored in the device's database folder when it is downloaded.

Here's the implemented code:

```java
public void uploadFile(String fileName) {
    File exampleFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("Login.db").getPath());

    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(exampleFile));
        writer.append("Example file contents");
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Upload failed", exception);
    }

    Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
        fileName,
        exampleFile,
        result -> Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Successfully uploaded: " + result.getKey()),
        storageFailure -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Upload failed", storageFailure)
    );
}

public void downloadFile() {
    Amplify.Storage.downloadFile(
        "Login.db",
        new File(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("Login.db") + ""),
        result -> Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Successfully downloaded: " + result.getFile().getName()),
        error -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp",  "Download Failure", error)
    );
}
```

I'm looking for some insight on this matter. I'm just not sure what is causing the file corruption. I was thinking it could be the file path but I believe that is being navigated correctly.

Comment: S3 is not a database. Why not user proper database, such as DynamoDB?

Comment: Why are you writing data to the file before uploading it?

Comment: What logging mode are you using? WAL or Journal? If WAL are you making sure that the database is fully checkpointed (close the database)? If not and the WAL file `Login.db-wal` is not empty then you need to copy the `Login.db-wal` and possibly the `Login.db-shm` files as well as `Login.db`. See https://sqlite.org/wal.html. Since Android 9 WAL is the default mode see https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/compatibility-wal

Comment: @Marcin I 100% agree with you. This project is a class project and we had already started using SQLite. It is completely inefficient to be using this way but I'm met with friction when suggesting DynamoDB or aurora.

Comment: I believe it's using Journal Pragma. I checked the logcat and it spits out the error:
`E/SQLiteLog: (26) file is not a database in "PRAGMA journal_mode"
E/SQLiteDatabase: Database corruption detected in open()
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is not a database (code 26 SQLITE_NOTADB): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode`

Comment: @AnonCoward I appreciate you pointing this out to me. It had completely skipped my mind that this was a database file not and something like a textfile. I believe removing this has resolved my issue.
Many thanks to all who stopped and helped <3

Comment: How big is the file (should be at least 4k)? Why `writer.append("Example file contents");`? I'd suggest checking the header. The first 16 bytes should be 16 bytes (in hex): 53 51 4c 69 74 65 20 66 6f 72 6d 61 74 20 33 00. Bytes at offset 18 and 19 will be 1 if journal else 2 if WAL. see https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html. Database isn't encrypted?

Comment: @MikeT you're completely correct. It was the action of writing to the file that was corrupting it I believe.  I thank you kindly sir for your help.

Comment: @LEXERA.EXE I added an answer assuming that the append was the issue that also includes code that checks the header.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your issue is that the file is in fact corrupted and probably due to you using `writer.append("Example file contents");` and saving a file that contains just that.

You could perhaps add code to do some checks before uploading and after downloading a file.

The following is a snippet from code that does as such (in this case checking that an asset is a valid sqlite file, it's perhaps a little over the top) :-

```
/**
 * DBHEADER
 * The the header string, the first 16 bytes, of the SQLite file
 *  This should never be changed.
 */
private static final String DBHEADER = "SQLite format 3\u0000"; // SQLite File header first 16 bytes

/**
 * Constants that represent the various stages of the copy
 */
private static final int
        STAGEOPENINGASSETFILE = 0,
        STAGEOPENINGDATABASEFILE = 1,
        STAGECOPYING = 3,
        STAGEFLUSH = 4,
        STAGECLOSEDATABSE = 5,
        STAGECLOSEASSET = 6,
        STAGEALLDONE = 100
                ;
/**
 * Constants for message codes
 */
private static final int
        MSGCODE_EXTENDASSETFILE_ADDEDSUBDIRECTORY = 20,
        MSGCODE_EXTEANDASSETFILE_EXTENDEDFILENAME = 21,
        MSGCODE_CHECKASSETFILEVALIDTY_OPENEDASSET = 30,
        MSGCODE_CHECKASSETFILEVALIDITY_OPENFILED = 31,
        MSGCODE_CHECKASSETFILEVALIDITY_NOTSQLITEFILE = 32,
        MSGCODE_CHECKASSETFILEVALIDITY_VALIDSQLITEFILE = 33,
        MSGCODE_COPY_FAILED = 40,
        MSGCODE_COPY_OK = 41
                ;

/**
 * The default buffer size, can be changed
 */
private static final int DEFAULTBUFFERSIZE = 1024 * 32; // 32k buffer

....


/**
 * Check that the asset file to be copied exists and optionally is a valid
 * SQLite file
 * @param cntxt                     The Context
 * @param extendedAssetFilename     The asset file name including subdirectories
 * @param showstacktrace            true id to show the stack-trace if an exception as trapped
 * @param checkheader               true if the SQLite file header should be checked
 * @return                          true if the checks are ok
 */
public static boolean checkAssetFileValidity(Context cntxt, String extendedAssetFilename, boolean showstacktrace, boolean checkheader) {
    boolean rv = true;
    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = cntxt.getAssets().open(extendedAssetFilename);
        messages.add(
                new Msg(
                        MSGCODE_CHECKASSETFILEVALIDTY_OPENEDASSET,
                        Msg.MESSAGETYPE_INFORMATION,
                        "Successfully Opened asset file " + extendedAssetFilename
                )
        );
        if (checkheader) {
            byte[] fileheader = new byte[DBHEADER.length()];
            is.read(fileheader,0,fileheader.length);
            if (!(new String(fileheader)).equals(DBHEADER)) {
                messages.add(
                        new Msg(
                                MSGCODE_CHECKASSETFILEVALIDITY_NOTSQLITEFILE,
                                Msg.MESSAGETYPE_ERROR,
                                "Asset file " +
                                        extendedAssetFilename +
                                        " is NOT an SQlite Database, instead found " + (new String(fileheader))
                        )
                );
                is.close();
                return false;
            } else {
                messages.add(
                        new Msg(
                        MSGCODE_CHECKASSETFILEVALIDITY_VALIDSQLITEFILE,
                                Msg.MESSAGETYPE_INFORMATION,
                                "Successfully validated asset file " + extendedAssetFilename +
                                        " . It has a valid SQLite Header."
                        )
                );
            }
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        messages.add(
                new Msg(
                        MSGCODE_CHECKASSETFILEVALIDITY_OPENFILED,
                        Msg.MESSAGETYPE_ERROR,
                        "Unable to open asset " + extendedAssetFilename + "."
                )
        );
        if (showstacktrace) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return rv;
}
```

- the Msg class and associated methods haven't been included, they are just for logging messages. Shout if you want them added.

The main thing is checking the header.

Comment: God bless sir, I appreciate the help a lot.